# XMPP Incoming and Outgoing File Delegate not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to implement file transfer using XMPP. Below is a snippet of my code. Now the problem is, delegate methods of XMPPOutGoingFileTransfer and XMPPIncomingFileTransfer is not getting called. I dig out the framework for a solution but got no success. I don't know where i'm going wrong. Any type of help would be appreciated.

P.S: I'm new to iOS Development :D

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<XMPPStreamDelegate,XMPPOutgoingFileTransferDelegate,XMPPIncomingFileTransferDelegate>{
XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer *SendFileStream;
XMPPIncomingFileTransfer *receiveFileStream;
}
@end
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
SendFileStream = [[XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer alloc] init];
receiveFileStream = [[XMPPIncomingFileTransfer alloc] init];
receiveFileStream.autoAcceptFileTransfers = YES;
[SendFileStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[receiveFileStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think people don't prefer using XMPP or my question was so silly that they didn't bother to answer!!! Any ways whatever the reason is, i got solution to my problem and now it's my responsibility to answering it!

I achived what i wanted by just adding this two line of code:

```
[SendFileStream activate:xmppStream];
[receiveFileStream activate:xmppStream];
```

By adding this your delegate methods will start calling! :)

Comment: I used OpenFire as server and Adium as Client.